# Rails: if record exists then use this record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I use the result of an if condition in Rails? Something like:

```
if @edits.where(:article_id => a.id).first
  THIS.body.html_safe
else
  a.body.html_safe
end
```

How on earth do I access the result of that condition? That being the **THIS** record?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write in one line:

```
(@edits.where(:article_id => a.id).first || a).body.html_safe
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the assignment within the `if` statement.

```
if edit = @edits.where(:article_id => a.id).first
  edit.body.html_safe
else
  a.body.html_safe
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting such logic in view or helper is very ugly. It's not View's job to judge these.

Better alternative:

```
# Article model
def default_edit
  edits.first
end

# Articles Controller
def show
  article = Article.find(params[:article])
  @article = article.default_edit || article
end

# view: no need to do anything, just plain obj
<%= @article.body %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find_by` or `find_by_*` to avoid the nasty `.where().first`

```
if edit = Edit.find_by(article_id: article.id)
  edit.body.html_safe
else
  article.body.html_safe
end
```